# Vue 3 - Could not find a declaration file for module 'xyz'

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to import packages that I used `npm install xyz --save` to install using the ES6 or require statements but I keep getting the `Could not find a declaration file for module 'xyz'` error message. When googling the error, everyone's solution seems to point at the module missing a .ts file with a declaration. However, all those fixes seem to also involve the project being a typescript project which my project is not. Does anyone know what would cause this issue and how to fix it?